# Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I'm having the following problem with a Maven project on our Jenkins server while running the Sonarqube maven plugin in a Jenkins pipeline.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:54 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-14T11:42:51+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 74M/606M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project pandora-parent-pom: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: src/main/webapp/images/D??rogations.ep
   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: src/main/webapp/images/D??rogations.ep
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:80)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: src/main/webapp/images/D??rogations.ep
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPath.resolve(AbstractPath.java:53)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.path(DefaultInputFile.java:83)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.file(DefaultInputFile.java:75)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.PathPattern$RelativePathPattern.match(PathPattern.java:101)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.LanguageDetection.isCandidateForLanguage(LanguageDetection.java:124)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.LanguageDetection.language(LanguageDetection.java:97)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.InputFileBuilder.completeAndComputeMetadata(InputFileBuilder.java:98)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer$1.call(FileIndexer.java:164)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer$1.call(FileIndexer.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The file itself is named Dérogations.ep .

The part of the Jenkinsfile which contains the Sonar execution

```
stage('Sonar') {
                withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
                    updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: 'sonar', state: 'running')
                    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'ec266a3e-2586-4b2c-b0bb-386603d5a4ef', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
                        sh "export"
                        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS -Pcoverage-per-test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore"
                        sh "export"
                        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS -Dsonar.branch=${env.BRANCH_NAME} -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore"
                        sh "export"
                        jacoco()                    
                    }
                    updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: 'sonar', state: 'success')
                }
            }
```

The export call returns (amongst others) these params, which I assigned to our build node.

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_COLLATE='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8'
```

The maven-compiler-plugin and maven-resources-plugin are also configured in UTF-8 and the Sonar logs also suggest that everything is nicely in UTF-8 (except for one file which is in ISO-8859)

```
[INFO] -------------  Scan MP services jenkins
[INFO] Base dir: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services
[INFO] Working dir: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] 299 files indexed
[INFO] Quality profile for java: MP
[INFO] Sensor Lines Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=14ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor
[INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 7
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan
[INFO] 293 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 196/293 files analyzed, current file: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/src/main/java/be/MP/xxx/MP/dao/impl/HistoriqueActionServiceImpl.java
[INFO] 283/293 files analyzed, current file: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/src/main/java/be/MP/xxx/MP/service/impl/SourceAuthentiqueServiceImpl.java
[INFO] 293/293 source files have been analyzed
[WARNING] Classes not found during the analysis : [javax.portlet.PortletRequest]
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=21386ms
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan
[INFO] 6 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 6/6 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=334ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=21757ms
[INFO] Sensor PmdSensor
[INFO] Execute PMD 5.4.2...
[INFO] Java version: 1.7
[INFO] PMD configuration: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/sonar/pmd.xml
[INFO] PMD configuration: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/sonar/pmd-unit-tests.xml
[INFO] Execute PMD 5.4.2 done: 2375 ms
[INFO] Sensor PmdSensor (done) | time=2379ms
[INFO] Sensor CheckstyleSensor
[INFO] Execute Checkstyle 7.3...
[INFO] Checkstyle configuration: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/sonar/checkstyle.xml
[INFO] Checkstyle charset: UTF-8
[INFO] Execute Checkstyle 7.3 done: 1605 ms
[INFO] Sensor CheckstyleSensor (done) | time=1607ms
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor
[INFO] SCM provider for this project is: git
[INFO] 299 files to be analyzed
[INFO] 299/299 files analyzed
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=3669ms
[INFO] Sensor FindBugs Sensor
[INFO] Loading findbugs plugin: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/sonar/findbugs/fb-contrib.jar
[INFO] Loading findbugs plugin: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/sonar/findbugs/findsecbugs-plugin.jar
[INFO] Findbugs output report: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  org.junit.runners.model.Statement
  org.junit.Assert
  org.assertj.core.api.Assertions
  org.assertj.core.api.AbstractIntegerAssert
  org.assertj.core.api.ListAssert
  org.assertj.core.api.AbstractListAssert
  org.junit.rules.TestRule
  org.h2.Driver
  org.assertj.core.groups.Tuple
[INFO] Sensor FindBugs Sensor (done) | time=23684ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor
[INFO] Property 'sonar.junit.reportsPath' is deprecated. Use property 'sonar.junit.reportPaths' instead.
[INFO] parsing [/workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/surefire-reports]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=114ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor
[INFO] Analysing /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] No information about coverage per test.
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor (done) | time=512ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoItSensor
[INFO] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/jacoco-it.exec
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoItSensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor
[INFO] Analysing /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analysing /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Services/target/sonar/jacoco-overall.exec
[INFO] No information about coverage per test.
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor (done) | time=212ms
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor (done) | time=2ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=119ms
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=4ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer
[INFO] JavaCpdBlockIndexer is used for java
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=283ms
[INFO] -------------  Scan MP Web UI jenkins
[INFO] Base dir: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Webui
[INFO] Working dir: /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Webui/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: src/main/webapp, pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] Index files
[WARNING] Invalid character encountered in file /workspace/workspace/MP-pipeline_jenkins-HSMRPDPBA52NIJUTYCTAAM5Q76P4BDGNRHEXQ6VTGOHHOGM5XPRQ/Webui/src/main/webapp/js/my/widgets/templates/TutorialWidget.html at line 3 for encoding UTF-8. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
```

The only way to make it work is adding `-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8` when doing the sonarqube analysis. Why does maven need this setting for the sonar-maven-plugin but not for anything else (like `mvn clean install`) ?

Comment: SonarQube might fork a process that doesn't properly handle the environment, maybe?

Comment: By chance, have you written this filename in one of your pom.xml? Likely in `<sonar.sources>` property.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam: It's not mentioned in the pom. It's just a resource file.

Comment: @mkobit maybe ... not sure how I can check what the forked process has as environment variables (if it's forked)